# Oracle SQL - Delete rows without logging

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I am going to delete millions of rows in each batch which I cannot delete them together since there are too many rows. I was thinking of deleting rows with no log but I did bot find anything. Is there anybody could help me to write a delete no log query?

My query would be like:

```
DELETE
FROM MyTable
WHERE TO_CHAR(MyDate, 'YYYYMM') = 202101
```

even I jus consider one month(It is about 6 million records) I cannot delete them

Comment: Does your DB have Partitioning licence?

Comment: Please abandon the idea of circumventing the redo logs. If something goes wrong you have a good chance of ending up with an unusable database. If you can't remove the rows monthly-wise, why not day-wise? A non-working method is always worse than a working method. How many rows would remain after the delete? Else renaming the table and copying the rows you'd like to keep to a new table with the old name could be an option

Comment: How many rows are in the table? How many of these rows are you going to delete? One month = 6M rows ? Or several months (a multiple of 6M)? Is your issue that you are getting "ORA-01555: snapshot too old"? Does the table have child tables (i.e. tables with foreign key constraints in this table)? Are there delete triggers on the table?

Comment: I am going to delete them little by little and then insert same data with some changes(I know I can update them but they have to many problems)in total my db has around 5 billions records and yes it has partition. in just month 01 we have around 6M. deleting data from this table took a lot of time and I think my table will be locked after some hours.

Answer (score 3):

Delete operations are always `logging`, and also require a lot of `undo`, that is why they could be expensive in terms of performance when a huge number of rows are involved. Also, if you have indexes, the rows must be deleted there too.

There are several options, but they strongly depend of your environment. I would try two approaches

*I am using parallel with degree 8. If you have less or more CPU in your database server, you could play with the degree. I would not use too much degree in the delete, but I would use as much as possible in the option 2*

**Option 1 ( use parallel dml )**

```
alter session enable parallel dml ;
delete /*+parallel(a,8) */ from myTable a where TO_CHAR(MyDate, 'YYYYMM') = 202101 ;
commit;
```

**Option 2 ( use CTAS and Truncate/Insert )**

```
alter session enable parallel dml;
alter session enable parallel ddl;

create table MyBkpTable parallel compress nologging pctfree 0 
as select /*+parallel(a,8) */ * from MyTable a 
where TO_CHAR(MyDate, 'YYYYMM') != 202101 ;

truncate table MyTable reuse storage ;

insert /*+append parallel(a,8) */ into MyTable a 
select /*+parallel(b,8) */ * from MyBkpTable b;

commit;
```

If you have a lot of indexes on the table, mark all indexes as unusable and use `alter session set skip_unusable_indexes=true` before running the insert append. Then at the end, rebuild all indexes.

**Update**

As the table is partitioned, to benefit from `partition pruning` you might use ( **as long as the partition key is MyDate** )

```
delete /*+parallel(a,8) */ from myTable a where MyDate >= date '2021-01-01' and MyDate < date '2021-02-01' ;
```

or even better, just truncate all those partitions

```
alter table myTable truncate partition <<partition_name>>
```

Comment: `where MyDate >= date '2021-01-01' and MyDate < date '2021-02-01'` to leverage partitioning. For the second approach partitioning may also be used: `exchange partition` with rebuild of indexes instead of `insert ... select...`

Comment: @astentx, I saw the last comment now, when he say that the table has partitions.  when I wrote the answer, I did not know whether the table was or not partitioned

Comment: Filter on pure date is more reliable than `to_char` in any case.